# Neumann boundary condition is not satisfied

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I want to solve the diffusion equation on a disk centered at (0,0) with a radius of 1. I also want the flux at a radius of 0.8 to be zero. I have this initial condition at time zero:

```
u[x, y, 0] == Exp[(-x^2 - y^2)/0.01] + 10*Exp[-(((x - 1)^2 + (y)^2)/0.01)]
```

The initial condition looks like this:

[image]

The solution after time 50 looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that I expected because the flux is zero at radius of 0.8 then at the distance more than 0.8 from the origin the value of variable `u[x,y,t]` should be different from that of at distances shorter than 0.8. However, everything looks equilibrated.

Here is the whole code:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{
        Laplacian[u[x, y, t], {x, y}] == D[u[x, y, t], t] + 
          NeumannValue[0., {x, y} ∈ RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Disk[{0, 0}, 0.8]]],
        u[x, y, 0] == Exp[(-x^2 - y^2)/0.01] + 10*Exp[-(((x - 1)^2 + y^2)/0.01)]},
       u, {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 1],
       {t, 0, 50}
      ]

Plot3D[sol[x, y, 0], {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 1], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Here it is necessary to solve two problems: 1) on the disk `x^2+y^2<=0.8^2`, 2) on the ring `0.8^2<=x^2+y^2<=1`.

Comment: Thank you. In this link I reduced my real problem and asked a new question. 
I think I will delete this question then.

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193789/how-to-apply-different-equation-to-different-part-of-a-geometry-in-pde

Comment: Why delete?  It's an interesting question!

Comment: @mjw Yuo are right. At first I thought the other question I asked covers this one. But they seem unrelated. I will not delete the question.

Comment: @MOON, Thanks.  Hope to have time later to work on it.  In any case, looking forward to seeing it develop.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to have an internal `NeumannValue`:

We generate a mesh with an internal boundary:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[Annulus[{0, 0}, {8/10, 1}], 
   "RegionHoles" -> None];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

The mesh has boundary markers:

```
mesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"]
{1, 2}
```

Visualize the mesh with it's boundary elements grouped by the markers:

```
mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
  "MeshElementStyle" -> {Blue, Orange}]]
```

[image]

Solve the equation:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y, t], {x, y}] == 
     D[u[x, y, t], t] + NeumannValue[1, ElementMarker == 1], 
    u[x, y, 0] == 
     Exp[(-x^2 - y^2)/0.01] + 10*Exp[-(((x - 1)^2 + y^2)/0.01)]}, 
   u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, {t, 0, 50}];
```

And visualize the result:

```
Plot3D[sol[x, y, 50], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Why `NeumannValue[1,...` ? The way I understand the question ("flux at a radius of 0.8 to be zero") it should be `NeumannValue[0,...`

Comment: Though I don't find the question clear. In my interpretation, it could be reformulated as to 2 independent problems.

Comment: @andre314, because with `NeumannValue[0,...] you do not see anything. The numerical offset is too small. I also find the question not that clear, so I started with what I gathered and wanted to see what OP had to say.