# How to apply different equations to different parts of a geometry in PDE?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, nonlinear, chemistry

I want to solve two coupled partial differential equations on two dimension.
There are two variables `v` and `m`. The geometry is a disk. The variable `v` diffuses inside the disk until it reaches the boundary and then it converts to variable `m`. Variable `m` then diffuses on the boundary, on the edge of the disk. Variable `m` does not exist inside the disk, it only exists on the boundary. 
In the diagram below you see the summary of the problem:
[image]

I use the set of equations below to define the problem: 
[image]

The first equation describes the diffusion of variable `v` inside the disk.

The second equation describes the conversion of variable `v` to variable `m` (the term `alpha*v(x,y,t)`) and the diffusion of variable `m` on the boundary of the disk, here it is a circle.

The last equation is the boundary condition at the boundary of the disk which accounts for the conversion of variable `v` to variable `m`. On the left ∇ is the gradient operator which indicates the flux of variable `v` on the boundary. It will appear as the Neumann boundary condition:

```
NeumannValue[-1*alpha*v[x, y, t], x^2 + y^2 == 1]
```

**Problem:**

My problem is that how I should tell Mathematica that in the system of equations below (also shown above before) the first equation applies to the disk and the second equation applies to the boundary of the disk? The way I solved it below, the value of variable `m` is calculated on the entire of the disk which is not desired. `m` has value only on the boundary while it diffuses there.

[image]

Here is the code in Mathematica, The symmetric initial condition of `v` is just for simplification, otherwise the initial distribution of `v` does not have to be symmetric or Gaussian and in practice it should be a random distribution. Also the Neumann boundary condition in general will depend on the value of other variables which only exist on the boundary (here for simplification it is not the case). For example protein (variable) `m` could detach from the boundary and converts to protein (variable) `v` with a rate proportional to `m`.:

```
alpha = 1.0;
geometry = Disk[];

sol = NDSolveValue[{D[v[x, y, t], t] == 
     D[v[x, y, t], x, x] + D[v[x, y, t], y, y] + 
      NeumannValue[-1*alpha*v[x, y, t], x^2 + y^2 == 1],
    D[m[x, y, t], t] == 
     D[m[x, y, t], x, x] + D[m[x, y, t], y, y] + alpha*v[x, y, t], 
    m[x, y, 0] == 0, v[x, y, 0] == Exp[-((x^2 + y^2)/0.01)]}, {v, 
    m}, {x, y} \[Element] geometry, {t, 0, 10}];

v = sol[[1]];
m = sol[[2]];

ContourPlot[v[x, y, 1], {x, y} \[Element] geometry, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[m[x, y, 10], {x, y} \[Element] geometry, PlotRange -> All,
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Adding `DirichletCondition[m[x, y, t] == 0, x^2 + y^2 < 1]` to enforce the value of `m` inside the geometry (here the disk) gives this error:

```
NDSolveValue::bcnop: No places were found on the boundary where x^2+y^2<1 was True, so DirichletCondition[m==0,x^2+y^2<1] will effectively be ignored.
```

I hope at the end I can reproduce the results of the paper below in which several proteins diffuse inside a sphere and on its surface and convert to each other on the surface. The paper is open access:

https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1003396

**Physical interpretation**

The variable `v` and `m` represent two proteins. Protein `v` diffuses freely inside the cytosol (inside of the cell, here represented as a disk). Protein `m` is a membrane-bound protein that is it attaches to the cell's membrane (here the boundary of the disk) and only can exist as a membrane-bound protein. The protein `v` diffuses freely inside the disk and reaches the membrane or the boundary. There it converts to protein `m` with a rate that is proportional to the value of protein `v` on the membrane. The created membrane-bound protein `m` then diffuses on the membrane. Protein `m` cannot detach from the membrane and thus it must not exist in the cytosol (inside the disk).

**Edit**

I added this explanation to the question:
The symmetric initial condition of `v` is just for simplification, otherwise the initial distribution of `v` does not have to be symmetric or Gaussian and in practice it should be a random distribution. Also the Neumann boundary condition in general will depend on the value of other variables which only exist on the boundary (here for simplification it is not the case). For example protein (variable) m could detach from the boundary and converts to protein (variable) v with a rate proportional to m.

Comment: Please add your equations *as MMA code* as well.

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: You can formulate the problem in polar coordinates, see  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190754/ndsolve-error-in-2-d-heat-equation

Comment: We can solve the problem in 3D and reproduce the solution from the article.

Comment: What do you mean by "diffuses along the boundary", Is m a 2D problem of a 1D problem embedded into 2D?

Comment: @user21 I added the physical interpretation of the problem. `m` diffuses along the boundary which is a circle here.

Comment: So it is a 1D problem embedded in 2D on that boundary. You can not do that currently. You can not have diffusion along the boundary alone, Your boundary will will need a thickness, It can be very small. But I do not think that is an issue.

Comment: @user21 Are you aware if other software such as Matlab or Maple can do it?

Comment: I think you can do it with Mathematica just not the way you want to; besides the model you propose does not sound to good to me. In Nature there is no 1D boundary embedded in to 2D. That boundary always has a thickness.

Comment: @user21 If there is thickness then at least the problem must meet the continuity requirement. If there is thickness then `v` converts to `m` with a rate proportional to the value of `v` inside that thickness. However, the Neumann condition only take care of the `v`'s loss at the boundary. 

Does this specific problem (1D problem embedded in 2D) has any keyword or specific name?

Comment: I am not aware of such a name. Another thing to consider is the following. Your setup is symmetric and without convection. That means `v` is is going to reach the boundary at the same time everywhere. Then there can not be any diffusion along the boundary because there is no potential difference that could drive the diffusion.

Comment: I had a look at that paper and even there it is unclear what exactly they are simulating. I am somwhat confident that what you request was not possible in comsol 3.5a which they used. I'd contact the authors to clarify what they did.

Comment: @user21 Thanks for having a look at the paper.
The symmetric setup is just my own simplification. As you have seen in the paper the real problem is not symmetric: the initial distribution of proteins are random.

Comment: I think you'd need to figure out how the authors modeled those 'boundary' conditions.

Comment: @user21 in nature there is no 2D at all, but that does not stop you from simulating it, does it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since I have the code to solve the original problem described in the article [GDI-Mediated Cell Polarization in Yeast Provides Precise Spatial and Temporal Control of Cdc42 Signaling](https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1003396), I will give here a modification of this code for 2D. I did not manage to find the solution described in the article, since the system rather quickly evolves to an equilibrium state with all reasonable initial data. But something similar to clusters is obtained in 3D and a 2D.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]; mesh = 
 ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= R^2, {x, y}]; mesh1 = 
 ImplicitRegion[R1^2 <= x^2 + y^2 <= R^2, {x, y}];
d2 = .03; d3 = 11 ; R = 4; R1 = 
 7/2; N42 = 3000; NB = 6500; N24 = 1000; α1 = 0.2; α2 = 
 0.12 /60; α3 = 1 ; β1 = 0.266 ; β2 = 0.28 ; \
β3 = 1; γ1 = 0.2667 ; γ2 = 0.35 ; δ1 = \
0.00297;  δ2 = 0.35;
c0 = {.3, .65, .1}; m0 = {.0, .3, .65, 0.1};
C1[0][x_, y_] := 
 c0[[1]]*(1 + 
    Sum[RandomReal[{-.01, .01}]*
      Exp[-Norm[{x, y} - RandomReal[{-R, R}, 2]]^2], {i, 1, 10}]); 
C2[0][x_, y_] := 
 c0[[2]]*(1 + 
    Sum[RandomReal[{-.01, .01}]*
      Exp[-Norm[{x, y} - RandomReal[{-R, R}, 2]]^2], {i, 1, 10}]); 
C3[0][x_, y_] := 
 c0[[3]]*(1 + 
    Sum[RandomReal[{-.01, .01}]*
      Exp[-Norm[{x, y} - RandomReal[{-R, R}, 2]]^2], {i, 1, 10}]);
M1[0][x_, y_] := 
  m0[[1]]*(1 + 
     Sum[RandomReal[{-.01, .01}]*
       Exp[-Norm[{x, y} - RandomReal[{-R, R}, 2]]^2], {i, 1, 10}]);
M2[0][x_, y_] := 
 m0[[2]]*(1 + 
    Sum[RandomReal[{-.01, .01}]*
      Exp[-Norm[{x, y} - RandomReal[{-R, R}, 2]]^2], {i, 1, 10}]); 
M3[0][x_, y_] := 
 m0[[3]]*(1 + 
    Sum[RandomReal[{-.01, .01}]*
      Exp[-Norm[{x, y} - RandomReal[{-R, R}, 2]]^2], {i, 1, 10}]); 
M4[0][x_, y_] := 
 m0[[4]]*(1 + 
    Sum[RandomReal[{-.01, .01}]*
      Exp[-Norm[{x, y} - RandomReal[{-R, R}, 2]]^2], {i, 1, 10}]);
t0 = 1/2; n = 60;
Do[{C1[t], C2[t], C3[t]} = 
   NDSolveValue[{(c1[x, y] - C1[t - t0][x, y])/t0 - 
       d3*Laplacian[c1[x, y], {x, y}] == 
      NeumannValue[-C1[t - t0][x, 
           y] (β1*M4[t - t0][x, y] + β2) + β3*
         M2[t - t0][x, y], True], (c2[x, y] - C2[t - t0][x, y])/t0 - 
       d3*Laplacian[c2[x, y], {x, y}] == 
      NeumannValue[-γ1*M1[t - t0][x, y] + γ2*
         M3[t - t0][x, y], True], (c3[x, y] - C3[t - t0][x, y])/t0 - 
       d3*Laplacian[c3[x, y], {x, y}] == 
      NeumannValue[-δ1*M3[t - t0][x, y]*
         C3[t - t0][x, y] + δ2*M4[t - t0][x, y], True]}, {c1, 
     c2, c3}, {x, y} ∈ mesh, 
    Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
      InterpolationOrder -> {c1 -> 2, c2 -> 2, c3 -> 2}, 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01, "MeshOrder" -> 2}}];
  {M1[t], M2[t], M3[t], M4[t]} = 
   NDSolveValue[{(m1[x, y] - M1[t - t0][x, y])/t0 - 
       d2*Laplacian[m1[x, y], {x, y}] == -α3 M1[t - t0][x, 
         y] + β1 C1[t - t0][x, y] M4[t - t0][x, y] + 
       M2[t - t0][x, 
         y] (α2 + α1 M4[t - t0][x, y]), (m2[x, y] - 
          M2[t - t0][x, y])/t0 - 
       d2*Laplacian[m2[x, y], {x, y}] == β2 C1[t - t0][x, 
         y] + α3 M1[t - t0][x, y] - β3 M2[t - t0][x, y] +
        M2[t - t0][x, 
         y] (-α2 - α1 M4[t - t0][x, y]), (m3[x, y] - 
          M3[t - t0][x, y])/t0 - 
       d2*Laplacian[m3[x, y], {x, y}] == γ1 C2[t - t0][x, 
         y] M1[t - t0][x, y] - γ2 M3[t - t0][x, 
         y] - δ1 C3[t - t0][x, y] M3[t - t0][x, 
         y] + δ2 M4[t - t0][x, 
         y], (m4[x, y] - M4[t - t0][x, y])/t0 - 
       d2*
        Laplacian[m4[x, y], {x, y}] == δ1 C3[t - t0][x, 
         y] M3[t - t0][x, y] - δ2 M4[t - t0][x, y]}, {m1, m2, 
     m3, m4}, {x, y} ∈ mesh1, 
    Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
      InterpolationOrder -> {m1 -> 2, m2 -> 2, m3 -> 2, m4 -> 2}, 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01, 
        "MeshOrder" -> 2}}];, {t, t0, n*t0, t0}] // Quiet
```

In this FIG. shows how the concentration of components changes with time in volume (left) and on the membrane (right)

```
ListPlot[{Table[{t, C1[t][0, z] /. z -> .99*R}, {t, 0, n*t0, t0}], 
  Table[{t, C2[t][0, z] /. z -> .99*R}, {t, 0, n*t0, t0}], 
  Table[{t, C3[t][0, z] /. z -> .99*R}, {t, 0, n*t0, t0}]}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]

ListPlot[{Table[{t, M1[t][0, z] /. z -> .99*R}, {t, 0, n*t0, t0}], 
  Table[{t, M2[t][0, z] /. z -> .99*R}, {t, 0, n*t0, t0}], 
  Table[{t, M3[t][0, z] /. z -> .99*R}, {t, 0, n*t0, t0}], 
  Table[{t, M4[t][0, z] /. z -> .99*R}, {t, 0, n*t0, t0}]}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: fig1]

This figure shows a cluster on a membrane.

```
Table[DensityPlot[Evaluate[M1[t][x, y]], {x, -R, R}, {y, -R, R}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t*1.}], PlotPoints -> 50], {t, 10*t0, 
  n*t0, 10*t0}]
```

[image: fig2]

Simplify the code to solve the problem that MOON formulated. We use the initial data as in Henrik Schumacher answer and compare the result with his code with the options $\alpha =1,\theta =1$ and `"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01` at `t=0.4' (points on the figure). Here we use Cartesian coordinates, and the membrane is replaced by a narrow ring

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]; mesh = 
 ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= R^2, {x, y}]; mesh1 = 
 ImplicitRegion[R1^2 <= x^2 + y^2 <= R^2, {x, y}];
C0[x_, y_] := Exp[-20*Norm[{x + 1/2, y}]^2];
M0[x_, y_] := 0;
t0 = 1; d3 = 1; d2 = 1; R = 1; R1 = 9/10;
C1 = NDSolveValue[{D[c1[t, x, y], t] - 
      d3*Laplacian[c1[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 
     NeumannValue[-c1[t, x, y], True], c1[0, x, y] == C0[x, y]}, 
   c1, {t, 0, t0}, {x, y} ∈ mesh, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", InterpolationOrder -> {c1 -> 2}, 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01, "MeshOrder" -> 2}}];
M1 = NDSolveValue[{D[m1[t, x, y], t] - 
      d2*Laplacian[m1[t, x, y], {x, y}] == C1[t, x, y], 
    m1[0, x, y] == M0[x, y]} , 
   m1, {t, 0, t0}, {x, y} ∈ mesh1, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", InterpolationOrder -> {m1 -> 2}, 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01, "MeshOrder" -> 2}}];
```

[image: fig4]
Slightly modify the code of Michael E2 to remove osillation from the border. Compare the result with the solution of equations using the Henrik Schumacher model with $\alpha =1,\theta =1$ and `"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01` at `t=0.4' (points on the figure) and Michael E2 model

```
ClearAll[b, m, v, x, y, t];
alpha = 1.0; R1 = .9;
geometry = Disk[];

sol = NDSolveValue[{D[v[x, y, t], t] == 
    D[v[x, y, t], x, x] + D[v[x, y, t], y, y] + 
     NeumannValue[-1*alpha*v[x, y, t], x^2 + y^2 == 1], 
   D[m[x, y, t], t] == 
    UnitStep[
      x^2 + y^2 - R1^2] (D[m[x, y, t], x, x] + D[m[x, y, t], y, y] + 
       alpha*v[x, y, t]), m[x, y, 0] == 0, 
   v[x, y, 0] == Exp[-20*((x + .5)^2 + y^2)]}, {v, 
   m}, {x, y} ∈ geometry, {t, 0, 10}]

vsol = sol[[1]];
msol = sol[[2]];
```

[image: fig5]
The concentration distribution on the membrane in our model
[image: fig6]

The concentration distribution on the disk in Michael E2 model
[image: fig7]

Modifier code MK, add options in `NDSolve`. Compare the result with the solution of equations using the Henrik Schumacher model with $\alpha =1,\theta =1$ and `"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01` at `t=0.4' (points on the figure) and MK model. Note the good agreement of the data on the membrane (in both models, the Laplace operator on the circle is used)

```
alpha = 1.0;
geometry = Disk[];

{x0, y0} = {-.5, .0};

sol = NDSolve[{D[v[x, y, t], t] == 
     D[v[x, y, t], x, x] + D[v[x, y, t], y, y] + 
      NeumannValue[-1*alpha*v[x, y, t], x^2 + y^2 == 1], 
    v[x, y, 0] == Exp[-20*((x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2)]}, 
   v, {x, y} ∈ geometry, {t, 0, 10}, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", InterpolationOrder -> {v -> 2}, 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01, "MeshOrder" -> 2}}];

vsol = v /. sol[[1, 1]];

vBoundary[phi_, t_] := vsol[.99 Cos[phi], .99 Sin[phi], t]

sol = NDSolve[{D[m[phi, t], t] == 
     D[m[phi, t], {phi, 2}] + alpha*vBoundary[phi, t], 
    PeriodicBoundaryCondition[m[phi, t], phi == 2 π, 
     Function[x, x - 2 π]], m[phi, 0] == 0}, 
   m, {phi, 0, 2 π}, {t, 0, 10}];

msol = m /. sol[[1, 1]];
```

[image: fig8]

Finally, back to our source code. Compare the result with the solution of equations using the Henrik Schumacher model with $\alpha =1,\theta =1$ and `"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01` at `t=0.4' (points on the figure) and our model. We note a good coincidence of data on the membrane (in both models, an explicit Euler in time is used):

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]; mesh = 
 ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= R^2, {x, y}]; mesh1 = 
 ImplicitRegion[R1^2 <= x^2 + y^2 <= R^2, {x, y}];
d2 = 1; d3 = 1 ; R = 1; R1 = 9/10; 
C1[0][x_, y_] := Exp[-20*Norm[{x + 1/2, y}]^2];
M1[0][x_, y_] := 0;

t0 = 1/50; n = 20;
Do[C1[t] = 
   NDSolveValue[(c1[x, y] - C1[t - t0][x, y])/t0 - 
      d3*Laplacian[c1[x, y], {x, y}] == NeumannValue[-c1[x, y], True],
     c1, {x, y} ∈ mesh, 
    Method -> {"FiniteElement", InterpolationOrder -> {c1 -> 2}, 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01, "MeshOrder" -> 2}}];
  M1[t] = 
   NDSolveValue[(m1[x, y] - M1[t - t0][x, y])/t0 - 
      d2*Laplacian[m1[x, y], {x, y}] == C1[t][x, y] , 
    m1, {x, y} ∈ mesh1, 
    Method -> {"FiniteElement", InterpolationOrder -> {m1 -> 2}, 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01, 
        "MeshOrder" -> 2}}];, {t, t0, n*t0, t0}] // Quiet
```

[image: fig9]

As I promised, let's move on to the 3D model. We consider a system of 7 nonlinear equations for seven functions depending on four variables [t,x,y,z]. Three functions are defined in the whole region and four functions are defined on the border (membrane). We use an approximate model in which the membrane is replaced by a spherical layer. 
We have shown that in the case of 2D this approximation agrees well with other models. 
Initial system of equations and boundary conditions I took from the article as

[image: fig11]

We use the following notation {C1, C2, C3} = {cD, cB, cG}; {M1, M2, M3, M4} = {mT, mD, mB, mBG}. Functions {c1,c2,c3,m1,m2,m3,m4} are used at each time step.
Here is the working code, but there are warnings that the solution in 3D is not unique. This example shows the formation of a cluster on a membrane.
The initial data for each function are given as a constant + 10 Gaussian distribution with random parameters. The number of random parameters has little effect on the dynamics, but affects the number of clusters on the membrane.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]; mesh = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= R^2, {x, y, z}]; mesh1 = ImplicitRegion[(9*(R/10))^2 <= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= R^2, {x, y, z}]; 
d2 = 0.03; d3 = 11; R = 4; N42 = 3000; NB = 6500; N24 = 1000; α1 = 0.2; α2 = 0.12/60; α3 = 1; β1 = 0.266; β2 = 0.28; β3 = 1; γ1 = 0.2667; γ2 = 0.35; 
  δ1 = 0.00297; δ2 = 0.35; 
c0 = {3, 6.5, 1}; m0 = {3, 3, 6.5, 1}; a = 1/30; 
C1[0][x_, y_, z_] := c0[[1]] + Sum[RandomReal[{-a, a}]*Exp[-Norm[{x, y, z} - RandomReal[{-R, R}, 3]]^2], {i, 1, 10}]; 
  C2[0][x_, y_, z_] := c0[[2]] + Sum[RandomReal[{-a, a}]*Exp[-Norm[{x, y, z} - RandomReal[{-R, R}, 3]]^2], {i, 1, 10}]; 
  C3[0][x_, y_, z_] := c0[[3]] + Sum[RandomReal[{-a, a}]*Exp[-Norm[{x, y, z} - RandomReal[{-R, R}, 3]]^2], {i, 1, 10}]; 
M1[0][x_, y_, z_] := m0[[1]] + Sum[RandomReal[{-a, a}]*Exp[-Norm[{x, y, z} - RandomReal[{-R, R}, 3]]^2], {i, 1, 10}]; 
  M2[0][x_, y_, z_] := m0[[2]] + Sum[RandomReal[{-a, a}]*Exp[-Norm[{x, y, z} - RandomReal[{-R, R}, 3]]^2], {i, 1, 10}]; 
  M3[0][x_, y_, z_] := m0[[3]] + Sum[RandomReal[{-a, a}]*Exp[-Norm[{x, y, z} - RandomReal[{-R, R}, 3]]^2], {i, 1, 10}]; 
  M4[0][x_, y_, z_] := m0[[4]] + Sum[RandomReal[{-a, a}]*Exp[-Norm[{x, y, z} - RandomReal[{-R, R}, 3]]^2], {i, 1, 10}]; 
t0 = 1/10; n = 40; 
Quiet[Do[{C1[t], C2[t], C3[t]} = NDSolveValue[{(c1[x, y, z] - C1[t - t0][x, y, z])/t0 - d3*Laplacian[c1[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 
        NeumannValue[(-C1[t - t0][x, y, z])*(β1*M4[t - t0][x, y, z] + β2) + β3*M2[t - t0][x, y, z], True], 
       (c2[x, y, z] - C2[t - t0][x, y, z])/t0 - d3*Laplacian[c2[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == NeumannValue[(-γ1)*M1[t - t0][x, y, z] + γ2*M3[t - t0][x, y, z], True], 
       (c3[x, y, z] - C3[t - t0][x, y, z])/t0 - d3*Laplacian[c3[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == NeumannValue[(-δ1)*M3[t - t0][x, y, z]*C3[t - t0][x, y, z] + 
          δ2*M4[t - t0][x, y, z], True]}, {c1, c2, c3}, Element[{x, y, z}, mesh], 
      Method -> {"FiniteElement", InterpolationOrder -> {c1 -> 2, c2 -> 2, c3 -> 2}}]; {M1[t], M2[t], M3[t], M4[t]} = 
     NDSolveValue[{(m1[x, y, z] - M1[t - t0][x, y, z])/t0 - d2*Laplacian[m1[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == (-α3)*M1[t - t0][x, y, z] + 
         β1*C1[t - t0][x, y, z]*M4[t - t0][x, y, z] + M2[t - t0][x, y, z]*(α2 + α1*M4[t - t0][x, y, z]), 
       (m2[x, y, z] - M2[t - t0][x, y, z])/t0 - d2*Laplacian[m2[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == β2*C1[t - t0][x, y, z] + α3*M1[t - t0][x, y, z] - 
         β3*M2[t - t0][x, y, z] + M2[t - t0][x, y, z]*(-α2 - α1*M4[t - t0][x, y, z]), 
       (m3[x, y, z] - M3[t - t0][x, y, z])/t0 - d2*Laplacian[m3[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == γ1*C2[t - t0][x, y, z]*M1[t - t0][x, y, z] - γ2*M3[t - t0][x, y, z] - 
         δ1*C3[t - t0][x, y, z]*M3[t - t0][x, y, z] + δ2*M4[t - t0][x, y, z], (m4[x, y, z] - M4[t - t0][x, y, z])/t0 - d2*Laplacian[m4[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 
        δ1*C3[t - t0][x, y, z]*M3[t - t0][x, y, z] - δ2*M4[t - t0][x, y, z]}, {m1, m2, m3, m4}, Element[{x, y, z}, mesh1], 
      Method -> {"FiniteElement", InterpolationOrder -> {m1 -> 2, m2 -> 2, m3 -> 2, m4 -> 2}}]; , {t, t0, n*t0, t0}]]
```

The distribution of $m_T,m_D$ on the membrane

```
Table[DensityPlot3D[
  Evaluate[M1[t][x, y, z]], {x, -R, R}, {y, -R, R}, {z, -R, R}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t*1.}]], {t, 2*t0, n*t0, 6*t0}]

Table[DensityPlot3D[
  Evaluate[M2[t][x, y, z]], {x, -R, R}, {y, -R, R}, {z, -R, R}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t*1.}]], {t, 2*t0, n*t0, 6*t0}]
```

[image: fig12]

The distribution of $m_T,m_D$ on the membrane with multiple clusters
[image: fig13]

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have the comsol file for this simulation? Could you upload that some place for people to inspect?

Comment: @user21 No, it's just a Wolfram Math code that I wrote for this problem. But I see that even MOON does not show interest in the real problem, but prefers a toy model.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks for your answer. It would be nice if you could upload the code you wrote for the paper. 
I simplified the real problem so that others can provide answers without unnecessary complication and also I could understand their answers.

Comment: @MOON I will prepare an answer with an explanation of the 3D model. Although it differs from 2D only in an extra variable `z`. You can test the 2D model and ask questions.

Comment: @Alex Wow, you put a lot of effort into this. It is indeed reassuring to see that all these methods generate comparable results.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I checked your 3D model. It looks good. Now we need to compare your model with others, and also consider the nonlinear case.

Comment: @MOON I added code for 3D model.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @MOON You're welcome!

Answer (score 13):

Denote the disk by $\varOmega$ and its boundary by $\varGamma = \partial \varOmega$. I'd prefer to denote the function residing on the boundary by $u \colon \varGamma \to \mathbb{R}$; the function on the whole disk is called $v \colon \varOmega \to \mathbb{R}$.

Our aim is to solve the system of parabolic equations
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
  \partial_t u - c_2 \varDelta_{\varGamma} u 
&= 
\alpha \, v 
&& 
\text{on $\varGamma$,}
\\
\partial_t v - c_1 \varDelta_{\varOmega} v 
&= 
0 
&& 
\text{in $\varOmega$,}
\\
N v - \alpha v 
&= 
0 
&& \text{on $\varGamma$.}
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

### Spatial discretization

We integrate against the test functions $\varphi \colon \varGamma \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\psi \colon \varOmega \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\psi|_{\partial \varOmega} = 0$ and $N \psi = 0$.

(I assume that $\alpha$, $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constant.)

This leads to the following *weak formulation* of the PDE:
$$
\begin{aligned}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\int_{\varGamma} u(t,x) \, \varphi(x) \, \mathrm{vol}_{\partial \varOmega}(x) + c_2 \, \int_{\varGamma} \langle \mathrm{d} u(t,x) , \mathrm{d} \varphi(x) \rangle \, \mathrm{vol}_{\varGamma} (x) &= \alpha \int_{\varGamma} v(t,x) \, \varphi(x)\, \mathrm{vol}_{\varGamma} (x)
\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\int_{\varOmega} v(t,x) \, \psi(x) \, \mathrm{vol}_{\varOmega}(x) + c_1 \, \int_{\varOmega} \langle \mathrm{d} v(t,x) , \mathrm{d} \psi(x) \rangle \, \mathrm{vol}_{\varOmega} (x) &= 0 
\\
\int_{\varGamma} \big(\tfrac{\partial v}{\partial \nu}(t,x) + \alpha v(t,x)\big) \, \varphi(x) \, \mathrm{vol}_{\varGamma} (x)
&=
0
\end{aligned}
$$

We discretization this in space by finite elements leading to the following entities ($\mathrm{b}$ stands for boundary):

- time-dependent vectors $\mathbf{u}(t)$ and $\mathbf{v}(t)$,
- stiffness matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{A}_{\mathrm{b}}$; *Mathematica's* FEM tools can produce $\mathbf{A}$ but not $\mathbf{A}_{\mathrm{b}}$ in general; I will provide code for it below.
- mass matrices $\mathbf{M}$ and $\mathbf{M}_{\mathrm{b}}$; same here: $\mathbf{M}$  can be produced easily; $\mathbf{M}_{\mathrm{b}}$ requires special treatment).
- the matrix $\mathbf{N}$ encoding the Neumann operator times boundary mass matrix; this consists of those rows of $\mathbf{A}$ that belong to boundary degrees of freedom.
- the matrix $\mathbf{D}$ encoding the Dirichlet boundary operator; this consists of those rows of the identity matrix that belong to boundary degrees of freedom, multiplied by $\mathbf{M}_{\mathrm{b}}$.

Then this reads as the following system of ODEs:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \mathbf{M}_{\mathrm{b}} \, \mathbf{u}(t) + c_2 \, \mathbf{A}_{\mathrm{b}} \, \mathbf{u}(t) &= \alpha \, \mathbf{D} \, \mathbf{v}(t)
\quad \text{for boundary vertices}
\\
\tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \mathbf{M} \, \mathbf{v}(t) + c_1 \, \mathbf{A} \, \mathbf{v}(t) &= 0
\quad \text{for interior(!) vertices}
\\
(\mathbf{N} + \alpha \, \mathbf{D})\, \mathbf{v}(t) &= 0 \quad \text{for boundary vertices}
\end{aligned}
$$

### Time discretization

I am going to supply code for the $\theta$-method with $\theta \in {[1/2,1]}$. For $\theta = 1/2$, this is the Crank-Nicolson scheme, while for $\theta = 1$, this boils down to the implicit Euler scheme.

We pick a time step $\tau > 0$ and set $\mathbf{u}_i = \mathbf{u}(i \, \tau)$ and $\mathbf{v}_i = \mathbf{v}(i \, \tau)$. One may think of $\mathbf{u}(t)$ and $\mathbf{v}(t)$ being the piecewise-linear interpolations of the $\mathbf{u}_i$ and the $\mathbf{v}_i$, repectively. (Purists from numerical analysis won't like this because of nuances between several Petrov-Galerkin schemes, but I am not going to argue with zealots here.)

$$
\begin{aligned}
\tfrac{1}{\tau}
(\mathbf{M}_{\mathrm{b}} \, \mathbf{u}_{i+1} - \mathbf{M}_{\mathrm{b}} \, \mathbf{u}_{i}) + c_2 \, (1-\theta) \, \mathbf{A}_{\mathrm{b}} \, \mathbf{u}_{i} + c_2 \, \theta \, \mathbf{A}_{\mathrm{b}} \, \mathbf{u}_{i+1} &= \alpha \, (1-\theta)\, \mathbf{D} \, \mathbf{v}_{i} + \alpha \, \theta \, \mathbf{D} \, \mathbf{v}_{i+1}
&&\text{for boundary vertices}
\\
\tfrac{1}{\tau}(\mathbf{M} \, \mathbf{v}_{i+1} - \mathbf{M} \, \mathbf{v}_{i}) + c_1 \, (1-\theta) \, \mathbf{A} \, \mathbf{v}_i + c_1 \, \theta \, \mathbf{A} \, \mathbf{v}_{i+1} &= 0
&& \text{for interior(!) vertices}
\\
(\mathbf{N} + \alpha \, \mathbf{D}) \, \mathbf{v}_{i+1} &= 0 
&&\text{for boundary vertices}
\end{aligned}
$$
This provides us with a linear system to determine $\mathbf{u}_{i+1}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{i+1}$ from $\mathbf{u}_{i}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{i}$.

#### Side remark

Actually, I am not 100% sure whether the last line shouldn't better read as
$$
(1-\theta) \, (\mathbf{N} + \alpha \, \mathbf{D}) \, \mathbf{v}_{i} + \theta \, (\mathbf{N} + \alpha \, \mathbf{D}) \, \mathbf{v}_{i+1} = 0.
$$
However, I guess this may lead to spurious oscillations for $\theta \approx 1/2$. So I better leave it as it is.

Let's multiply by $\tau$ and let's put all expressions containing the "new" time steps $\mathbf{u}_{i+1}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{i+1}$ to the left of the equality sign and all the other terms to the right:

$$
\begin{aligned}
(\mathbf{M}_{\mathrm{b}} + c_2 \, \tau \, \theta \, \mathbf{A}_{\mathrm{b}} )\, \mathbf{u}_{i+1} 
- \tau \, \alpha \, \theta \, \mathbf{D} \, \mathbf{v}_{i+1}
&= 
(
\mathbf{M}_{\mathrm{b}}
- c_2 \, \tau \, (1-\theta) \, \mathbf{A}_{\mathrm{b}}
) \, \mathbf{u}_{i} 
+ \tau \, \alpha \, (1-\theta)\, \mathbf{D} \, \mathbf{v}_{i}
&&\text{for boundary vertices}
\\
(\mathbf{M} + c_1 \, \tau \, \theta \, \mathbf{A}) \, \mathbf{v}_{i+1} 
&= 
(\mathbf{M}- c_1 \, \tau \, (1-\theta) \, \mathbf{A}) \, \mathbf{v}_i 
&& \text{for interior(!) vertices}
\\
(\mathbf{N} + \alpha \, \mathbf{D}) \, \mathbf{v}_{i+1} &= 0 && \text{for boundary vertices}
\end{aligned}
$$

We may write this as a single linear system
$$\mathbf{L}_+ \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{u}_{i+1}\\\mathbf{v}_{i+1}\end{pmatrix}
=
\mathbf{L}_- \, \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{u}_{i}\\\mathbf{v}_{i}\end{pmatrix}
$$
with the block matrices
$$
\mathbf{L}_+ 
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
(
  \mathbf{M}_{\mathrm{b}} + c_2 \, \tau \, \theta \, \mathbf{A}_{\mathrm{b}} 
)
&
- \tau \, \alpha \, \theta \, \mathbf{D}
\\
0 & \mathbf{B}_+
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{L}_- 
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
(
  \mathbf{M}_{\mathrm{b}} 
  - c_2 \, \tau \, (1-\theta) \, \mathbf{A}_{\mathrm{b}}
)
&
\tau \, \alpha \, (1-\theta)\, \mathbf{D}
\\
0 & \mathbf{B}_-
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\mathbf{B}_+$ and $\mathbf{B}_-$ encode the second and third equations: This is done by overwriting those rows of the second equations that belong to boundary degrees of freedom by the Robin-boundary conditions from the third equations; see also the implementation below.

### Implementation - <s>2D case</s> nD

First, we need to execute <s>the first code block from the section "Code Dump" in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172603)</s> the following code block. It provides us with tools to assemble mass and stiffness matrices for general `MeshRegions`.

*I completely reworked this section in order to provide more convenient user interface by caching frequently used results in `PropertyValue`s of `MeshRegions`.*

```
SetAttributes[AssemblyFunction, HoldAll];

Assembly::expected = "Values list has `2` elements. Expected are `1` elements. Returning prototype.";

Assemble[pat_?MatrixQ, dims_, background_: 0.] := 
  Module[{pa, c, ci, rp, pos}, 
   pa = SparseArray`SparseArraySort@SparseArray[pat -> _, dims];
   rp = pa["RowPointers"];
   ci = pa["ColumnIndices"];
   c = Length[ci];
   pos = cLookupAssemblyPositions[Range[c], rp, Flatten[ci], pat];
   Module[{a}, 
    a = <|"Dimensions" -> dims, "Positions" -> pos, "RowPointers" -> rp, "ColumnIndices" -> ci, "Background" -> background, "Length" -> c|>;
    AssemblyFunction @@ {a}]];

AssemblyFunction /: a_AssemblyFunction[vals0_] := 
  Module[{len, expected, dims, u, vals, dat}, 
   dat = a[[1]];
   If[VectorQ[vals0], vals = vals0, vals = Flatten[vals0]];
   len = Length[vals];
   expected = Length[dat[["Positions"]]];
   dims = dat[["Dimensions"]];
   If[len === expected, 
    If[Length[dims] == 1, u = ConstantArray[0., dims[[1]]];
     u[[dat[["ColumnIndices"]]]] = AssembleDenseVector[dat[["Positions"]], vals, {dat[["Length"]]}];
     u, 
     SparseArray @@ {Automatic, dims, dat[["Background"]], {1, {dat[["RowPointers"]], dat[["ColumnIndices"]]}, AssembleDenseVector[dat[["Positions"]], vals, {dat[["Length"]]}]}}], 
    Message[Assembly::expected, expected, len];
    Abort[]]];

cLookupAssemblyPositions = Compile[{{vals, _Integer, 1}, {rp, _Integer, 1}, {ci, _Integer, 1}, {pat, _Integer, 1}}, 
   Block[{k, c, i, j}, 
    i = Compile`GetElement[pat, 1];
    j = Compile`GetElement[pat, 2];
    k = Compile`GetElement[rp, i] + 1;
    c = Compile`GetElement[rp, i + 1];
    While[k < c + 1 && Compile`GetElement[ci, k] != j, ++k];
    Compile`GetElement[vals, k]], 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   Parallelization -> True, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

AssembleDenseVector = 
  Compile[{{ilist, _Integer, 1}, {values, _Real, 1}, {dims, _Integer, 1}}, 
   Block[{A}, 
    A = Table[0., {Compile`GetElement[dims, 1]}];
    Do[
     A[[Compile`GetElement[ilist, i]]] += Compile`GetElement[values, i],
     {i, 1, Length[values]}
     ];
    A],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];


getRegionLaplacianCombinatorics = Compile[{{ff, _Integer, 1}},
   Flatten[
    Table[
     Table[{Compile`GetElement[ff, i], Compile`GetElement[ff, j]}, {i,
        1, Length[ff]}], {j, 1, Length[ff]}],
    1],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

SetAttributes[RegionLaplacianCombinatorics, HoldFirst]
RegionLaplacianCombinatorics[R_] /; Region`Mesh`Utilities`SimplexMeshQ[R] := Module[{result},
   result = PropertyValue[R, "RegionLaplacianCombinatorics"];
   If[result === $Failed,
    result = Assemble[
      Flatten[
       getRegionLaplacianCombinatorics[
        MeshCells[R, RegionDimension[R], "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]]],
       1
       ], {1, 1} MeshCellCount[R, 0]
      ];
    R = SetProperty[R, "RegionLaplacianCombinatorics" -> result];
    ];
   result
   ];

SetAttributes[RegionElementData, HoldFirst]
RegionElementData[R_] /; Region`Mesh`Utilities`SimplexMeshQ[R] := 
  Module[{result},
   result = PropertyValue[R, "RegionElementData"];
   If[result === $Failed,
    result = Partition[ MeshCoordinates[R][[Flatten[ MeshCells[R, RegionDimension[R], "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]]]]], RegionDimension[R] + 1
      ];
    R = SetProperty[R, "RegionElementData" -> result];
    ];
   result
   ];

SetAttributes[RegionBoundaryFaces, HoldFirst]
RegionBoundaryFaces[R_] /; Region`Mesh`Utilities`SimplexMeshQ[R] := 
  Module[{result},
   result = PropertyValue[R, "RegionBoundaryFaces"];
   If[result === $Failed,
    result = With[{n = RegionDimension[R]},
      MeshCells[R, n - 1, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1,Random`Private`PositionsOf[Length /@ R["ConnectivityMatrix"[n - 1, n]]["AdjacencyLists"],1]]]
      ];
    R = SetProperty[R, "RegionBoundaryFaces" -> result];
    ];
   result
   ];

SetAttributes[RegionBoundaryVertices, HoldFirst]
RegionBoundaryVertices[R_] /; Region`Mesh`Utilities`SimplexMeshQ[R] :=
   Module[{result},
   result = PropertyValue[R, "RegionBoundaryVertices"];
   If[result === $Failed,
    result = DeleteDuplicates[Sort[Flatten[RegionBoundaryFaces[R]]]];
    R = SetProperty[R, "RegionBoundaryVertices" -> result];
    ];
   result
   ];

getRegionMassMatrix[n_, m_] := getRegionMassMatrix[n, m] = 
   Block[{xx, x, PP, P, UU, U, VV, V, f, Df, u, Du, g, integrand, quadraturepoints, quadratureweight, λ, simplex, center}, 
    λ = 1 - 1/Sqrt[2 + n];
    xx = Table[Indexed[x, i], {i, 1, n}];
    PP = Table[Compile`GetElement[P, i, j], {i, 1, n + 1}, {j, 1, m}];
    UU = Table[Indexed[U, i], {i, 1, n + 1}];
    f = x \[Function] Evaluate[PP[[1]] + Sum[Indexed[x, i] (PP[[i + 1]] - PP[[1]]), {i, 1, n}]];
    Df = x \[Function] Evaluate[D[f[xx], {xx}]];
    (*the Riemannian pullback metric with respect to f*)
    g = x \[Function] Evaluate[Df[xx]\[Transpose].Df[xx]];
    (*affine function u and its derivatives*)
    u = x \[Function] Evaluate[ UU[[1]] + Sum[Indexed[x, i] (UU[[i + 1]] - UU[[1]]), {i, 1, n}]];
    Du = x \[Function] Evaluate[D[u[xx], {xx}]];
    integrand = x \[Function] Evaluate[1/2 D[u[xx] u[xx] Sqrt[Abs[Det[g[xx]]]], {UU, 2}]];
    simplex = Join[ConstantArray[0, {1, n}], IdentityMatrix[n]];
    center = Mean[simplex];
    quadraturepoints = Table[λ center + (1 - λ) y, {y, simplex}];
    quadratureweight = 1/(n + 1)!;
    With[{code = N[quadratureweight Total[integrand /@ quadraturepoints]]}, 
     Compile[{{P, _Real, 2}}, code, CompilationTarget -> "C", 
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
      RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
     ]
    ];

SetAttributes[RegionMassMatrix, HoldFirst]
RegionMassMatrix[R_] /; Region`Mesh`Utilities`SimplexMeshQ[R] := 
  Module[{result},
   result = PropertyValue[R, "RegionMassMatrix"];
   If[result === $Failed,
    result = RegionLaplacianCombinatorics[R][
      Flatten[ getRegionMassMatrix[RegionDimension[R], RegionEmbeddingDimension[R]][RegionElementData[R]]]
      ];
    R = SetProperty[R, "RegionMassMatrix" -> result];
    ];
   result
   ];


getRegionLaplacian[n_, m_] := getRegionLaplacian[n, m] = 
   Block[{xx, x, PP, P, UU, U, VV, V, f, Df, u, Du, g, integrand, quadraturepoints, quadratureweight, λ, simplex, center}, 
    λ = 1 - 1/Sqrt[2 + n];
    xx = Table[Indexed[x, i], {i, 1, n}];
    PP = Table[Compile`GetElement[P, i, j], {i, 1, n + 1}, {j, 1, m}];
    UU = Table[Indexed[U, i], {i, 1, n + 1}];
    f = x \[Function] Evaluate[PP[[1]] + Sum[Indexed[x, i] (PP[[i + 1]] - PP[[1]]), {i, 1, n}]];
    Df = x \[Function] Evaluate[D[f[xx], {xx}]];
    (*the Riemannian pullback metric with respect to f*)
    g = x \[Function] Evaluate[Df[xx]\[Transpose].Df[xx]];
    (*affine function u and its derivatives*)
    u = x \[Function] Evaluate[UU[[1]] + Sum[Indexed[x, i] (UU[[i + 1]] - UU[[1]]), {i, 1, n}]];
    Du = x \[Function] Evaluate[D[u[xx], {xx}]];
    integrand = x \[Function] Evaluate[ 1/2 D[Du[xx].Inverse[g[xx]].Du[xx] Sqrt[Abs[Det[g[xx]]]], {UU, 2}]];
    simplex = Join[ConstantArray[0, {1, n}], IdentityMatrix[n]];
    center = Mean[simplex];
    quadraturepoints = Table[λ center + (1 - λ) y, {y, simplex}];
    quadratureweight = 1/(n + 1)!;
    With[{code = N[quadratureweight Total[integrand /@ quadraturepoints]]}, 
     Compile[{{P, _Real, 2}}, 
      code, 
      CompilationTarget -> "C", 
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
      Parallelization -> True, 
      RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
      ]
     ]
    ];

SetAttributes[RegionLaplacian, HoldFirst]
RegionLaplacian[R_] /; Region`Mesh`Utilities`SimplexMeshQ[R] := 
  Module[{result},
   result = PropertyValue[R, "RegionLaplacian"];
   If[result === $Failed,
    result = RegionLaplacianCombinatorics[R][
      Flatten[getRegionLaplacian[RegionDimension[R], RegionEmbeddingDimension[R]][RegionElementData[R]]]
      ];
    R = SetProperty[R, "RegionLaplacian" -> result];
    ];
   result
   ];

SetAttributes[RegionDirichletOperator, HoldFirst]
RegionDirichletOperator[R_] /; Region`Mesh`Utilities`SimplexMeshQ[R] :=
   Module[{result},
   result = PropertyValue[R, "RegionDirichletOperator"];
   If[result === $Failed,
    result = IdentityMatrix[
       MeshCellCount[R, 0],
       SparseArray,
       WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision
       ][[RegionBoundaryVertices[R]]];
    R = SetProperty[R, "RegionDirichletOperator" -> result];
    ];
   result
   ];

SetAttributes[RegionNeumannOperator, HoldFirst]
RegionNeumannOperator[R_] /; Region`Mesh`Utilities`SimplexMeshQ[R] := 
  Module[{result},
   result = PropertyValue[R, "RegionNeumannOperator"];
   If[result === $Failed,
    result = RegionLaplacian[R][[RegionBoundaryVertices[R]]];
    R = SetProperty[R, "RegionNeumannOperator" -> result];
    ];
   result
   ];

getRegionReactionMatrix[n_, m_] := getRegionReactionMatrix[n, m] = 
   Block[{xx, x, PP, P, UU, U, VV, V, f, Df, u, v, w, g, integrand, quadraturepoints, quadratureweights, λ, ω, simplex, center},
    xx = Table[Indexed[x, i], {i, 1, n}];
    PP = Table[Compile`GetElement[P, i, j], {i, 1, n + 1}, {j, 1, m}];
    UU = Table[Compile`GetElement[U, i], {i, 1, n + 1}];
    VV = Table[Compile`GetElement[V, i], {i, 1, n + 1}];
    f = x \[Function] Evaluate[PP[[1]] + Sum[Indexed[x, i] (PP[[i + 1]] - PP[[1]]), {i, 1, n}]];
    Df = x \[Function] Evaluate[D[f[xx], {xx}]];
    (*the Riemannian pullback metric with respect to f*)

    g = x \[Function] Evaluate[Df[xx]\[Transpose].Df[xx]];
    (*affine function u and its derivatives*)
    u = x \[Function] Evaluate[UU[[1]] + Sum[Indexed[x, i] (UU[[i + 1]] - UU[[1]]), {i, 1, n}]];
    v = x \[Function] Evaluate[VV[[1]] + Sum[Indexed[x, i] (VV[[i + 1]] - VV[[1]]), {i, 1, n}]];
    integrand = 
     x \[Function] Evaluate[1/2! D[u[xx]^2 v[xx] Sqrt[Abs[Det[g[xx]]]], {UU, 2}]];

    (*Gauss quadrature of order 3*)
    λ = (1 + n)/(3 + n);
    ω = -(1 + n)^2/4 /(2 + n);
    simplex = Join[ConstantArray[0, {1, n}], IdentityMatrix[n]];
    center = Mean[simplex];
    quadraturepoints = Join[{center}, ConstantArray[center, n + 1] λ + (1 - λ) simplex];
    quadratureweights = Join[{ω/n!}, ConstantArray[(1 - ω)/(n + 1)!, n + 1]];
    With[{code = N[Dot[quadratureweights, integrand /@ quadraturepoints]]},
     Compile[{{P, _Real, 2}, {V, _Real, 1}},
      code, 
      CompilationTarget -> "C",
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
      Parallelization -> True,
      RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
      ]
     ]];

SetAttributes[RegionReactionMatrix, HoldFirst]
RegionReactionMatrix[R_, u_?VectorQ] /; 
   Region`Mesh`Utilities`SimplexMeshQ[R] := Module[{result},
   result = RegionLaplacianCombinatorics[R][
     Flatten[
      getRegionReactionMatrix[RegionDimension[R], RegionEmbeddingDimension[R]][
       RegionElementData[R],
       Partition[
        u[[Flatten[ MeshCells[R, RegionDimension[R], "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]]]]],
        RegionDimension[R] + 1
        ]
       ]
      ]
     ];
   result
   ];

getRegionReactionVector[n_, m_] := getRegionReactionVector[n, m] = 
   Block[{xx, x, PP, P, UU, U, VV, V, WW, W, f, Df, u, v, w, g, integrand, quadraturepoints, quadratureweights, λ, ω, simplex, center},
    xx = Table[Indexed[x, i], {i, 1, n}];
    PP = Table[Compile`GetElement[P, i, j], {i, 1, n + 1}, {j, 1, m}];
    UU = Table[Compile`GetElement[U, i], {i, 1, n + 1}];
    VV = Table[Compile`GetElement[V, i], {i, 1, n + 1}];
    WW = Table[Compile`GetElement[W, i], {i, 1, n + 1}];
    f = x \[Function] Evaluate[PP[[1]] + Sum[Indexed[x, i] (PP[[i + 1]] - PP[[1]]), {i, 1, n}]];
    Df = x \[Function] Evaluate[D[f[xx], {xx}]];
    (*the Riemannian pullback metric with respect to f*)

    g = x \[Function] Evaluate[Df[xx]\[Transpose].Df[xx]];
    (*affine function u and its derivatives*)
    u = x \[Function] Evaluate[UU[[1]] + Sum[Indexed[x, i] (UU[[i + 1]] - UU[[1]]), {i, 1, n}]];
    v = x \[Function] Evaluate[VV[[1]] + Sum[Indexed[x, i] (VV[[i + 1]] - VV[[1]]), {i, 1, n}]];
    w = x \[Function] Evaluate[WW[[1]] + Sum[Indexed[x, i] (WW[[i + 1]] - WW[[1]]), {i, 1, n}]];
    integrand = x \[Function] Evaluate[D[u[xx] v[xx] w[xx] Sqrt[Abs[Det[g[xx]]]], {UU, 1}]];

    (*Gauss quadrature of order 3*)
    λ = (1 + n)/(3 + n);
    ω = -(1 + n)^2/4 /(2 + n);
    simplex = Join[ConstantArray[0, {1, n}], IdentityMatrix[n]];
    center = Mean[simplex];
    quadraturepoints = Join[{center}, ConstantArray[center, n + 1] λ + (1 - λ) simplex];
    quadratureweights = Join[{ω/n!}, ConstantArray[(1 - ω)/(n + 1)!, n + 1]];
    With[{code = N[Dot[quadratureweights, integrand /@ quadraturepoints]]},
     Compile[{{P, _Real, 2}, {V, _Real, 1}, {W, _Real, 1}},
      code, CompilationTarget -> "C",
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
      Parallelization -> True,
      RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
      ]
     ]];

SetAttributes[RegionReactionVector, HoldFirst]
RegionReactionVector[R_, u_?VectorQ, v_?VectorQ] /; 
   Region`Mesh`Utilities`SimplexMeshQ[R] := Module[{result},
   result = With[{
      n = RegionDimension[R],
      flist = Flatten[MeshCells[R, RegionDimension[R], "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]]]
      },
     AssembleDenseVector[
      flist,
      Flatten[
       getRegionReactionVector[RegionDimension[R], RegionEmbeddingDimension[R]][
        RegionElementData[R],
        Partition[u[[flist]], n + 1],
        Partition[v[[flist]], n + 1]
        ]
       ],
      {MeshCellCount[R, 0]}
      ]
     ];
   result
   ];
```

### Application

```
dim = 2;
Ω = DiscretizeRegion[Ball[ConstantArray[0., dim]], MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> 0.05}];
Ωb = RegionBoundary[Ω];
```

This generates the Laplacian, mass, Neumann, and Dirichlet matrices:

```
A = RegionLaplacian[Ω];
M = RegionMassMatrix[Ω];

Ab = RegionLaplacian[Ωb];
Mb = RegionMassMatrix[Ωb];

Dir = RegionMassMatrix[Ωb].RegionDirichletOperator[Ω];
Neu = RegionNeumannOperator[Ω];
```

Setting some constants...

```
c1 = 1.;
c2 = 1.;

h = Max[PropertyValue[{Ω, 1}, MeshCellMeasure]];
τ = 0.5 h^2;

θ = 0.5;
α = 0.1;
```

I made a rather conservative choice for `τ`; it should lead to stable evolution and maximal convergence rates for all values of `θ` between `0.5` and `1.`. However, it might also be chosen significantly larger, in particular for `θ` close to `0.5`.

Writing the two helper matrices `Lplus` and `Lminus` and factorizing `Lplus` by creating a `LinearSolveFunction` object `S`.

```
bvertices = RegionBoundaryVertices[Ω];
Lplus = Module[{Bplus}, 
   Bplus = M + (τ θ c1) A;
   Bplus[[bvertices]] = (Neu + α Dir);
   ArrayFlatten[{{Mb + (τ θ c2) Ab, (-α τ θ) Dir}, {0., Bplus}}]
   ];

Lminus = Module[{Bminus}, 
   Bminus = M + (-τ (1 - θ) c1) A;
   Bminus[[bvertices]] *= 0.;
   ArrayFlatten[{{(Mb + (-τ (1 - θ) c2) Ab), (α τ (1 - θ)) Dir}, {0., Bminus}}]
   ];
S = LinearSolve[Lplus];
```

Next, we set initial conditions, solve the evolution problem with `NestList` and separate the solution parts.

```
u0 = ConstantArray[0., Length[bvertices]];
v0 = Map[X \[Function] Exp[-20 ((X[[1]] + 1/2)^2 + (X[[2]])^2)], MeshCoordinates[Ω]];
x0 = Join[u0, v0];

x = NestList[S[Lminus.#] &, x0, 5000]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
u = x[[;; , ;; Length[bvertices]]];
v = x[[;; , Length[bvertices] + 1 ;;]];
```

> 2.12089

Up to this point, things should work well for both `dim = 2` and `dim = 3` (apart from generating the initial condition as one might want to use a 3D Gaussian for `dim = 3`).

### Visualization

I haven't checked this against an analytical solution, yet (who can provide one?), but the results look quite plausible. Here is an animation showing the evolution of the functions $u$ and $v$; notice that $u$ has to be scaled up quite a bit to make it visible; so this might appear a bit unnatural at the first glance.

```
pts = MeshCoordinates[Ω];
bfaces = RegionBoundaryFaces[Ω];
faces = MeshCells[Ω, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]];
maxu = Max[u];
plot[i_] := Module[{p, q}, 
   p = q = Join[pts, Partition[v[[i]], 1], 2];
   q[[bvertices, 3]] = u[[i]]/(2 maxu);
   Show[Graphics3D[{Thick, ColorData[97][1], 
      GraphicsComplex[q, Line[bfaces]], EdgeForm[], 
      FaceForm[ColorData[97][2]], Specularity[White, 30], 
      GraphicsComplex[p, Polygon[faces]]}], Axes -> True, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "values"}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
    PlotRange -> {0, 1}]];
Manipulate[plot[i], {i, 1, Length[v], 1}]
```

[image]

Likewise, I have not checked the 3D case for correctness, yet.

### Towards the nonlinear problem

With more than two reactants, this is going to become quite messy, so I merely sketch how one should proceed from here.

The resulting chemical reaction systems typically contain parabolic equations with bilinear terms of the following form
$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\partial_t u_i - c^{(2)}_{i} \, \Delta_{\partial \varOmega} u_i 
&= 
\sum_j \alpha_{i,j}\, v_j 
+
\sum_{j,k} C^{\varGamma,\varGamma}_{i,j,k} \, u_j \, u_k
+
\sum_{j,k} C^{\varGamma, \varOmega}_{i,j,k} \, u_j \, v_k
&&
\text{on $\partial \varOmega$,} 
\\
\partial_t v_i - c^{(1)}_{i} \, \Delta_{\varOmega} v_i 
&= 
\sum_{j,k} C^{\varOmega,\varOmega}_{i,j,k} \, v_j \, v_k 
&&
\text{in $\varOmega$,} 
\\
N \, v_i + \sum_j \alpha_{j,i} \, v_i 
&= 
0 
&&
\text{on $\partial \varOmega$.} 
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
That means that in the weak formulation of this system, terms of the form
$$
\int_{\varGamma} u_j \, u_k \, \varphi \, \mathrm{vol}_{\varGamma},
\quad
\int_{\varGamma} u_j \, v_k \, \varphi \, \mathrm{vol}_{\varGamma}
\quad 
\text{and} 
\quad
\int_{\varOmega} v_j \, v_k \, \psi \, \mathrm{vol}_{\varOmega}
$$
will show up. Hence, one has to discretize expressions of the form
$$
   T(u,v,w) = \int_{M} u \, v \, w \, \mathrm{vol}_{M},
$$
where $M \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is a submanifold and $u$, $v$, $w \colon M \to \mathbb{R}$ are functions. 
Thus, one needs vector representations 
$$
\mathbf{R}(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}), \quad \mathbf{R}(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{w}), \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbf{R}(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})
$$
of the linear forms
$$
   T(\cdot,v,w), \quad T(u,\cdot,w), \quad \text{and} \quad T(u,v,\cdot).
$$
These are provided by the routines `RegionReactionVector` in the section "Implementation". The usage scheme is as simple as

```
RegionReactionVector[Ω, v, w]
```

and

```
RegionReactionVector[Ωb, vb, wb]
```

for vectors `v`, `w` and `vb`, `wb` representing functions on `Ω` and `Ωb`, respectively.

In order to compute the evolution of the system, it is also desirable to use (at least semi-)implicit methods. And for that, matrix representations 
$$
\mathbf{R}(\mathbf{u}), \quad \mathbf{R}(\mathbf{v}), \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbf{R}(\mathbf{w})
$$
of the bilinear forms
$$
   T(u,\cdot,\cdot), \quad T(\cdot,v,\cdot), \quad \text{and} \quad T(\cdot,\cdot,w)
$$
are required. These are provided by the routines `RegionReactionMatrix` in the section "Implementation". The usage scheme is as simple as

```
RegionReactionMatrix[Ω, w]
```

and

```
RegionReactionMatrix[Ωb, wb]
```

I'd like to point out that `RegionReactionMatrix` has to be reassembled in each each time iteration and that I therefore also included the speeding techniques from [this post of mine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/175328).

With the nonlinear terms, there is now a plethora of possibilities for the time discretization. One wouldn't try to make the time stepping fully implicit as this would require a non-linear solve in each time iteration. So one has to fiddle around a bit with semi-implicit methods. Maybe it already suffices to treat the reaction terms explicitly: This would correspond to setting $\theta = 0$ for those terms while keeping $\theta \geq \frac{1}{2}$ for all the other (linear) terms. But there are also other ways and I do not feel competent enough to tell in advance, which method will work best. Unfortunately, I also do not have the time to try it for myself.

Depending on the time discretization, also `Lplus` and `Lminus` might have to be rebuilt in each time iteration. This can be done in essentially the same fashion as I did it above by utilizing `ArrayFlatten` to piece the various mass-, diffusion-, and reaction matrices together.

If `Lplus` changes over time, a one-time factorization with `LinearSolve` won't be efficient anymore, and it will probably be better to employ a interative solver based on Krylov space techniques (see [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/193700) for example).

Comment: The code works. It is necessary to check on the real problem in which the three functions in the volume and the four at the boundary are nonlinearly connected.

Comment: I checked your 2D model in comparison with 4 other models (see my answer). Now check out the 3D model.

Comment: To solve a non-linear problem it is necessary to organize an iteration process, as in this problem https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193700/how-to-diminish-computation-time-when-nonlinearity-appears-in-2d-heat-conduction/193766#193766

Comment: Yes, @Alex, I know. I am going to sketch that but I can do only one thing at a time... =)

Comment: I have to stop here; the post hit its character limit.

Comment: Everything is clear, I will try to implement this algorithm on a real problem.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for your answer. I will learn a lot from it.

Comment: @MOON You're welcome.

Comment: Thank you @user21! Is there a chance that surface FEM will be included in future releases? I can image that it might be nontrivial to write a user friendly interface for that...

Comment: I think the interface is quite clear: `NDSolve[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 1, 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == 1 && y == 0]}, u, {x, 
   y} \[Element] Disk[]]`; You'd just specify a boundary only region. And in fact I suspect that some of the code already exists: `NeumannValue[u[x,y]....]` does operate on the boundary and contributes to the stiffness matrix. Don't hold your breath for this, but it is not completely out of the questions.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, ah thay should not be `Disk` but `Circle`, of course.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Do you any book explaining the method you used here in more detail?

Comment: @MOON Which method do you mean? FEM in general? FEM on surfaces? Or the time stepping?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher The space discretization of the weak solution by FEM in the beginning of your answer.

Comment: @MOON Ah, I see. Hm. That is quite standard; every textbook on finite elements with piecewise-linear shape function should do. For the details on the special treatment for finite elements on surfaces, you might find this helpful: https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/C.M.Elliott/DziEll13surfem.pdf

Answer (score 10):

What about:

1. Noting that equations 1 and 3 form a complete set, and solve them first, treating the remaining equation 2 for `m` afterwards.
2. Noting that your imposed initial conditions for `v` do not satisfy boundary conditions, i.e., they violate eq(3). If you insist to use Gaussian distribution, in this particular example the factor in the exponential can be easily calculated by hand.
3. Writing eq(2) solely in terms of boundary parametrisation, in this case, a polar angle `phi`. The tricky part here for curved surfaces in more dimensions would be to express the Laplacian, however, there are recipes how to do it n-dimesnions. Anyway, for a circle this is straightforwardly done by hand.
4. Note, that not surprisingly, our solution does not depend on 'phi' as the whole problem is rotational-symmetric.
5. Due to numerical reasons, I have defined `vBoundary` on a circle with a radius slightly smaller than `1`. Alternatively, one could use as a boundary an approximation of a unit circle used in the `InterpolatingFunction`, which would be necessary for more complex geometries anyhow.

I hope that helps with your investigations.

```
alpha = 1.0;
geometry = Disk[];

{x0, y0} = {.0, .0};

sol = NDSolve[{D[v[x, y, t], t] == 
D[v[x, y, t], x, x] + D[v[x, y, t], y, y] + 
NeumannValue[-1*alpha*v[x, y, t], x^2 + y^2 == 1], 
v[x, y, 0] == Exp[-(((x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2)/(2/alpha))]}, 
v, {x, y} \[Element] geometry, {t, 0, 10}]

sol[[1, 1]]

ContourPlot[v[x, y, 1] /. sol[[1, 1]], {x, y} \[Element] geometry, 
PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]

vsol = v /. sol[[1, 1]];

vBoundary[phi_, t_] := vsol[.99 Cos[phi], .99 Sin[phi], t]

sol = NDSolve[
{D[m[phi, t], t] == D[m[phi, t], {phi, 2}] + alpha*vBoundary[phi, t],
PeriodicBoundaryCondition[m[phi, t], phi == 2 \[Pi], 
Function[x, x - 2 \[Pi]]],
m[phi, 0] == 0
},
m, {phi, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {t, 0, 10}]

msol = m /. sol[[1, 1]]

huePlot[t_] := 
PolarPlot[1, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
ColorFunction -> 
Function[{x, y, phi, r}, Hue[msol[phi, t]/msol[0, t]]], 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False]

huePlot[1]
```

Comment: Looks like a viable approach. In 1) you mean: 'treating the remaining equation 2 for `m` afterwards', not equation 3, right?

Comment: @MK. Thank you. Your approach is interesting and I will keep it in mind. Unfortunately, the real problem involves boundary conditions which also depends on the value of variables which only live on the boundary. For example protein (variable) `m` could detach from the boundary and converts to protein (variable) `v` with a rate proportional to `m`. Then solving first only for `v` would not be enough because there is another flux term for `v` which now depends on `m`.

Comment: In such case other answers posted here may be more applicable

Comment: @user21 yes indeed, I've corrected that.

Comment: @MK. I compared the solution of the problem according to your model and the Henrik Schumacher model (see my answer).

Answer (score 9):

Since your initial value for `m` is zero, make the derivative zero inside the disk.

```
ClearAll[b, m, v, x, y, t];
alpha = 1.0;
geometry = Disk[];

sol = NDSolveValue[{D[v[x, y, t], t] == 
    D[v[x, y, t], x, x] + D[v[x, y, t], y, y] + 
     NeumannValue[-1*alpha*v[x, y, t], x^2 + y^2 == 1], 
   D[m[x, y, t], t] == 
    UnitStep[
      x^2 + y^2 - 1] (D[m[x, y, t], x, x] + D[m[x, y, t], y, y] + 
       alpha*v[x, y, t]),
   m[x, y, 0] == 0, v[x, y, 0] == Exp[-((x^2 + y^2)/0.01)]}, {v, 
   m}, {x, y} ∈ geometry, {t, 0, 10}]

vsol = sol[[1]];
msol = sol[[2]];

ContourPlot[msol[x, y, 10], {x, y} ∈ geometry, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

With a better geometry, you should be able to control `m` better (here `m` is constrained to be zero for a disk of radius `1/2`):

```
bm1 = ToBoundaryMesh[Disk[{0, 0}, 1], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.05}];
bm2 = ToBoundaryMesh[Disk[{0, 0}, 1/2], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.02}];
bele1 = bm1["BoundaryElements"];
bele2 = bm2["BoundaryElements"];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
  "Coordinates" -> Join[bm1["Coordinates"], bm2["Coordinates"]], 
  "BoundaryElements" -> 
   Join[bele1, 
    MapThread[#1[#2] &, {Head /@ bele2, 
      Length[bm1["Coordinates"]] + ElementIncidents[bele2]}]]]

ClearAll[b, m, v, x, y, t];
alpha = 1.0;
geometry = ToElementMesh[bmesh, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01];

sol = NDSolveValue[{D[v[x, y, t], t] == 
    D[v[x, y, t], x, x] + D[v[x, y, t], y, y] + 
     NeumannValue[-1*alpha*v[x, y, t], x^2 + y^2 == 1], 
   D[m[x, y, t], t] == 
    UnitStep[
      x^2 + y^2 - 1/4] (D[m[x, y, t], x, x] + D[m[x, y, t], y, y] + 
       alpha*v[x, y, t]),
   m[x, y, 0] == 0, v[x, y, 0] == Exp[-((x^2 + y^2)/0.01)]}, {v, 
   m}, {x, y} ∈ geometry, {t, 0, 10}]

vsol = sol[[1]];
msol = sol[[2]];

ContourPlot[msol[x, y, 0.1], {x, y} ∈ geometry, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The solution `msol` obtained by your answer is zero on the boundary for all the time. I think it should be non-zero because the variable `v` converts to variable `m` on the boundary and there is no decay term for `m`.  Even if somehow `m` at the end should be zero at least initially it should be non-zero because the first time that `v` reaches the boundary it converts to `m`.

Comment: @MOON I adapted what you indicated: "Adding` DirichletCondition[m[x, y, t] == 0, x^2 + y^2 < 1]` to enforce the value of m inside the geometry (here the disk) gives this error:"  I don't know what you meant, but you included `t` and I thought you meant for all time.

Comment: I tried to use `DirichletCondition[m[x, y, t] == 0, x^2 + y^2 < 1]` to keep `m` inside the disk zero while it should be non-zero at the boundary.
The second part of your answer is closer to what I need. However, there is still a small problem.
While `m` is zero in the disk with radius 1/2 and non-zero from r = 1/2 to r = 1, in the region r=1/2 to r=1 both `m` and `v` coexist. `v` is converted to `m` with a rate proportional to the value of `v` on the boundary (r = 1). If `m` exist for r<1 then `m` coverts from `v` with a rate that depends on the value of `v` for r<1.

Comment: @MOON I should admit that I answered without understanding what you could mean by `v` is converted to `m`: (1) In your TeX equations, there's no PDE governing the evolution of `m` except on the boundary. (2) The PDE in your code has `m` depending on both `m` and `v`, so both would have to coexist (even though I understood you to say you don't want them to). (3) It sounds to me that you might want a single solution that behaves piecewise, differently inside the small disk than outside it. The points (1) - (3) seem to be inconsistent, so I'm hoping you can clarify.

Comment: In Latex equations (now numbered) equation 1 governs the evolution of variable `v` inside the disk. Equation 2 governs the evolution of the `m` on the boundary and conversion of `v` to `m` on the boundary with a rate proportional to the value of `v` on the boundary. The affix of `on the boundary` in equation 2 tries to tell that `m` exist only on the boundary and it also depends on the value of `v` on the boundary.
I will add the physical meaning of the system to the question.

Comment: @MichaelE2  I compared the solution  according to your model and the model of Henrik Schumacher (see my answer).