# How to handle discontinuity in diffusion coefficient?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method, discontinuity, heat-equation

I am looking to solve the diffusion equation with a discontinuous jump in the diffusion coefficient. In 1D, the diffusion equation for $u(t,x)$ is:
$$
\partial_t u = \partial_x (D \partial_x u),
$$
where $D(x)$ is the spatially varying diffusion coefficient. Let's use $D(x) = 1$ if $x < 1$ and $D(x) = 3$ if $x > 1$.

---

**Question:** Is there a better/smarter way to handle the discontinuity than approximating the jump with a continuous function? Is there a way to solve the equation in a piecewise manner, on $x \in [0,1)$ with $D=1$, on $x \in (1,2]$ with $D=3$, and somehow impose the condition that $D^\text{left} \partial_x u^\text{left} = D^\text{right} \partial_x u^\text{right}$ at $x=1$?

---

What I am trying to avoid is the following approximation:

We can approximate the discontinuity in $D$ by a sharp continuous function.

```
diffConst[x_] := (1 + 2 LogisticSigmoid[50 (x - 1)])
```

```
Plot[diffConst[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 3}]
```

[image]

Then we can solve the equation like so, with a sufficiently fine-grained spatial discretization:

```
fun = NDSolveValue[
  {
   D[z[x, t], t] == D[diffConst[x] D[z[x, t], x], x],
   z[0, t] == 2,
   z[2, t] == 1,
   z[x, 0] == 2
   },
  z,
  {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 20},
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
        "MinPoints" -> 300}}}
 ]
```

Plot the solution:

```
Animate[
 Plot[fun[x, t], {x, 0, 2}],
 {t, 0, 5}
]
```

[image]

Comment: In principle, FEM would not require any continuity of the diffusion constant (just make sure that there is a mesh node at the jump point). But I am not sure whether one can access this feature from the high-level user interface...

Comment: Follow-up question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/218983/how-to-model-diffusion-through-a-membrane

Comment: @Henrik Do you have any tips on the follow-up question I just linked?

Comment: Well, I am afraid I would discretize both sides of the geometry separately, request the system matrices from the low-level FEM tools in _Mathematica_ and couple the system by hand (with a hand-written time integrator). That would probably not help you. I recall that we had a discussion about similar couplings (just one dimension higher and for more general interfaces) in [193789](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/193789). IIRC, @AlexTrounev understood pretty well how to set up things directly with `NDSolve`.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121739/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131542/1871

Comment: Somehow I missed this: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/PDEModelsOverview.html It almost certainly has comparable examples, but I will need some time to go through it.

Comment: This is explained, for example, in the section [Partial Differential Equations with Variable Coefficients](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#938383864)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to solve the equation in a piecewise manner :

```
diffConst[x_]:=If[x<1,1,3];

fun = NDSolveValue[
  {
   D[z[x, t], t] == D[diffConst[x] D[z[x, t], x], x],
   z[0, t] == 2,
   z[2, t] == 1,
   z[x, 0] == 2
   },
  z,
  {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 20},
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"(*, 
        "MinPoints" -> 300*)}}}
 ]
 Plot[{fun[x,0.4]},{x,0,2}]
```

[image]

Note that the function `diffConst[x] D[z[x, t], x]` is continuous :

```
derivative = D[fun[x, .4], {x}]
Plot[{diffConst[x] derivative}, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

This is very likely the solution you are expecting, because it corresponds to
most physical situations. (For example, in thermics, It means conservation of the flux of heat thru the point x=1)

Comment: Specifying FiniteElement is critical though, otherwise we get a continuous derivative, not a continuous flux

Comment: [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2063762/369701)

Comment: @Szabolcs, please see the section [What Triggers the Use of the Finite Element Method](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOptions.html#1993509248) in the documentation.